# View diff between working copy and HEAD in tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, head, working-copy

I am working on a small SVN project and I have checked out two working copies (one on my desktop, and one on my laptop). Due to some unforeseen changes, I edited both working copies and then committed the one on the desktop to the Repository.

Now, I want to figure out how to commit the changes I made on my laptop without messing everything up. 
I thought a good starting point would be to view the differences between the working copy on the laptop and the current HEAD revision but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Act like you are going to do a commit.  It will show you the list of changed files and you can then right click on each of those in the list to do a diff

Comment: All right.. thanks. 
Is it bad practice for one developer to have more than one working copy at a time?

Comment: @mahela007 - no, but **The Right Way (tm)** is update your (another) Working Copies after commit from one - and merge updates from repository (automatically of by hnd in case of conflicts). If your changed files have intersection in commit and local changes - you'll **must** to update - future commits from outdated WC will be blocked

Answer (score 2):

Just update WC on laptop and integrate committed changes. Before update you can see changes (local and remote) as file-lists, without context, using `TortoiseSVN` - `Check for modification` context menu

I modeled you case (changed two working copies with commit from one, with intersected changes). Screenshots from WC with local uncommitted changes

Without "Check Repository"

[image: Without Repo]

With "Check Repository"

[image: Without Repo]

On second screenshot you can see aggregated changes (both in WC and in repository after checkout)

- Hello.de modified on both sides, my commit from this WC will be blocked due to this fact
- Hello.eo modified only locally, usual diff show these changes
- Hello.fr was modified only in WC1

For any file in this list of modification you can use "Compare with... " from TSVN context-menu for this window and see changed parts

[image: Diff with TMerge]